# How to merge multiple text files into a single one, maintaining sorting of each, but merging sorting of all

Tags: java, sorting, batch-file, text

I have 6 text files. Each one is a playlist, specifically, each one contains a fully-qualified filename on each line, which are all in the same directory. But each of the 6 playlists contains files from a different folder. Also, each playlist is sorted alphabetically.

I would like to merge them all into a single text file, containing all of the lines from all of the individual text files.

I want the order to be random. However, I want the sort order of each of the 6 text files to be respected.

So the result could start like this:

```
C:\DirectoryE\fsdkfhj.avi
C:\DirectoryA\jsazlkfjh.mp4
C:\DirectoryC\aldfkgdl.avi
C:\DirectoryD\basfjkdfhdksdkj.avi
C:\DirectoryE\gsdfsad.mp4
C:\DirectoryD\mfsdhsfjs.avi
C:\DirectoryA\nsdfkghkjhdf.mpg
C:\DirectoryE\hfdsskdfkemn.mp4
C:\DirectoryB\afdskfdfk.mpg
```

(Ignore the file extensions -- they are just examples, which clearly do not affect alphabetical filename sorting.)

But notice the directories do NOT need to be in order (should be random). But the filenames in any given directory should be in alphabetical order.

Solution in DOS batch file would be preferred, solution in Java would also be acceptable. Thanks!

EDIT: I will provide responses to these solutions within 28 hours. I can say this much, that without testing they both look viable. I am absolutely blown away by the creativity shown in these solutions and the fact they were provided so quickly. I had no idea that this was how stackexchange even worked. Someday I will repay this generosity.

Comment: Which part is causing you difficulty?

Comment: and what have you tried till now?

Comment: Please do not confuse StackOverflow with a free code/script writing service! You need to share your efforts and precisely describe where you are stuck! Please learn [ask]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filenames=file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt file6.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
SET /a filecount=0
SET /a itemcount=0
SET /a maxtracks=0
FOR %%a IN (%filenames%) DO CALL :getname "%sourcedir%\%%~a"
)


:: Now DO the selection
:select
SET /a selection=(%RANDOM% %% filecount) + 101
FOR /L %%t IN (1,1,%maxtracks%) DO IF DEFINED $%selection%%%t (
 CALL >>"%outfile%" ECHO %%$%selection%%%t%%
 set "$%selection%%%t="
 SET /a itemcount-=1
 GOTO done
)
:done
IF %itemcount% gtr 0 GOTO select


GOTO :EOF
:: get tracknames and store to $1???
:getname
SET /a filecount+=1
SET /a dollar=filecount+100
SET /a tracks=0
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%p IN (
 'find /n /v "" ^<"%~1"'
) DO SET "$%dollar%%%p=%%q"&SET /a itemcount+=1&SET /a tracks+=1
IF %tracks% gtr %maxtracks% SET /a maxtracks=tracks
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Interesting exercise - even if it's strictly a request to write to a spec. since you've shown us no code.

For each file, read each line and record it in the variable `$`*filenumber+100linenumber*. Also count the number of tracks overall and in each individual playlist and calculate the maximum number of tracks in any individual playlist.

The reason for `filenumber+100` is that in the event of expansion to up to 99 files, file `1` and file `10` (or `11`) don't have the numbering system overlapping.

Having recorded every name, first select a random playlist (now numbered from 101) and detect whether the variable `$`*playlisttracknumber* exists, counting tracknumber from 1 to `maxtracks`. When the first one is detected, output its value and set its value to *empty*, decrement the total items left and goto `done` so that only one will be selected.

At `done` we have either selected a track or not, so we check the remaining filecount. If greater than 0, repeat the selection process which will eventually select all of the available tracks and `itemcount` will be reduced to 0 where we terminate.

---

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filenames=file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt file6.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
SET /a filecount=0
SET /a itemcount=0
SET /a maxtracks=0
SET /a limits=0
FOR %%a IN (%filenames%) DO CALL :getname "%sourcedir%\%%~a"
)
SET /a filecount=itemcount
:: Now DO the selection
:select
SET /a nbr=(%RANDOM% %% filecount)+1
SET /a selection=100
FOR %%t IN (%limits%) DO IF %%t leq %nbr% SET /a selection+=1
FOR /L %%t IN (1,1,%maxtracks%) DO IF DEFINED $%selection%%%t (
 CALL >>"%outfile%" ECHO %%$%selection%%%t%%
 set "$%selection%%%t="
 SET /a itemcount-=1
 GOTO done
)
:done
IF %itemcount% gtr 0 GOTO select


GOTO :EOF
:: get tracknames and store to $1???
:getname
SET /a filecount+=1
SET /a dollar=filecount+100
SET /a tracks=0
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%p IN (
 'find /n /v "" ^<"%~1"'
) DO SET "$%dollar%%%p=%%q"&SET /a itemcount+=1&SET /a tracks+=1
IF %tracks% gtr %maxtracks% SET /a maxtracks=tracks
SET "limits=%limits% %itemcount%"
GOTO :eof
```

Here's a slightly revised version which compensates for the different track counts.

It builds `limits` which is a list of the total number of tracks encountered after each file has been read, so it might be assigned `0 7 13 22` if there were 7,6 and 9 tracks. `filecount` is then assigned to the same value as `itemcount`.

In doing the selection, `nbr` is set to 1..totaltracks and `selection` is then set to 100+the number of `limits` entries which are less than or equal to `nbr`. Consequently, `selection` is set to 101 for `nbr`=1..7, 102 for 8..13 and 103 for 14..22. The result is that the file/album number selected is chosen in proportion to the length of the album in tracks.

Comment: Thank You! This worked to a great degree. But as you can see, it ended with a lot of the same directory at the end. I suspect that;s because that directory had so many of the files. But that works! I can watch these files in this order. Thank you very muhch for your help and I only hope that I can help you someday in return!

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "counter=0"
    for %%f in (*.txt) do (
        set "base=100000000"
        set /a "counter+=1"
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%~ff") do (
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            set /a "base+=(!random!%%1000)*100+counter"
            for %%b in (!base!) do (
                endlocal
                set "_l.%%b=%%a"
                set "base=%%b"
            )
        )
    )
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('set _l.') do echo(%%b
```

The basic idea is to prefix each line in the input files with a random number and then sort the list on this number.

- Files are iterated with a `for` command. It is written to process all the `.txt` files in the folder. If you prefer to process a closed list, change that line to something like

```
    for %%f in ( file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt x:\somewhere\otherfile.txt ) do
```

- Each file is read using a `for /f` command.
- For each file, the random sequence starts in `100000000` (padding) and sucesive random numbers are added for each line to generate an increasing sequence of numbers for each file and keep the sort order. To avoid generating the same random value for more than one file (one line from a file could overwrite the line from another), the random value generated for each line is multiplied by 100 and a counter (incremented for each file) is added.
- The read data is stored in environment variables named using the generated random number. This way we can later retrieve the variable list numerically sorted.
- Once all the data has been read, a `for /f` command will retrieve the list of defined variables (the list is retrieved already sorted) and output their values.

Comment: Thank You, MC ND! Your solution gave me almost the exact same result as Magoo's solution. The only difference being, that whereas the last 24 lines of his result were exactly the last 24 lines of my longest input file ("s1.txt"), the last 30 lines of your result were exactly the last 30 lines of "s1.txt". Again, however, that is probably to be expected since I never stated that "s1.txt" was so much longer than the other input files. I would really like to thank you both for spending your time on this problem and helping me to find a solution. You're both highly talented and generous souls.